# ExpressJs HTTP Streaming make me run out of disk space

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, disk, http-streaming

My express server

```
app.get('/data', (_, res) => {
    const interval = setInterval(
        () => res.write(`${Math.random().toString()}\n`),
        1000
    );
    res.on('close', () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

My client-side

```
const res = await fetch('/data')
const reader = res.body.getReader()
reader.read().then(data => {
    const { value, done} = data;
    console.log(value);
})
```

Everything working fine, data is streaming every second and log. However, whenever I refresh page or close it, the server-side start to filling up my disk space at rate of 100MB/second.

Best of my guess is that one single random number can't match with 100MB.

Answer (score 0):

Your client-side code reads only *one* chunk of the data from the server so that the server-side buffer fills up every second (although not by 100MB?). Does the problem still occur if you replace the client-side code with

```js
const res = await fetch('/data');
const reader = res.body.getReader();
while (!await reader.read().then(function({value, done}) {
  console.log(value);
  return done;
}));
```

?

Comment: I tried your solution. The problem is still. I run the app inside a docker container. Even after I delete the container, the disk is still counting down 100MB/second actually per 3-4 secs). I put in a console.log and notice that server did received on 'close' event. Anyway, the server is intended to keep writing update to client.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried again on different machines and I can conclude that the reason for this is Google Cloud Shell's bugs. It has nothing to do with Docker or ExpressJs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).